# Mockito NotAMockException when it clearly is

Tags: junit, mockito, spring-test

I am using the Spring Test framework along with Junit. I have a spring context file which i use for the test cases:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:spring/restTestContext.xml",
        "classpath:spring/webserviceContext.xml" })
@PrepareForTest(User.class)
public class RestTestsIT {

// This is a mock
@Autowired private AWSMailService mailService;
...
}
```

Within the restTestContext.xml I am creating a bean of type AWSMailService (which is actually a mock):

```
<bean id="mailService" name="mailService" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.acme.utils.email.AWSMailService" />
</bean>
```

Within the test I am trying to verify that the sendEmail() method was called on the mailService mock but I am getting a NotAMockException although calling toString() on the object tells me it is a mock:

```
public void testEmailSent() {
...
// Results in "Mock for AWSMailService, hashCode: 31777764"
System.out.println(mailService.toString());

// Results in NotAMockException
verify(mailService).sendEmail(any(String.class), ...);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Fixed it :) Apparently I have to wait 8 hours before I can answer my own question so I'll update tomorrow :(

Answer (score 1):

Is Spring creating a Proxy for this object, so that Mockito thinks it's not a mock, because youre getting a Proxy$34 class as an intermediate between the caller and your mock object?

Comment: Yes exactly, I worked around it by manually wiring up the mock

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was using mockito 1.8.1, in version 1.9.0 the issue has been fixed.

Now Mockito's valid mock algorithm has changed and has not conflict with spring proxied beans.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it :)

The problem was that Mockito was indeed creating  a Mock but Spring was then proxying it and Mockito isn't intelligent enough to work out that the there is a proxy around the mock.

I'm now manually creating the mocks in the unit test and wiring them up:

```
@Mock private AWSMailService mailService;
@Autowired private UserService userService;

@Before
public void setup() {
  ((UserServiceImpl) userService).setMailService(mailService);
}
```